# Sum items on column from different row

Tags: excel

I have this table "# items" in excel:

| QUARTER | # items |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 2022 | 1 |
| Q1 2023 | 3 |
| Q3 2022 | 2 |
| Q1 2022 | 3 |
| Q1 2022 | 2 |
| Q1 2023 | 3 |

This table is daily updated with new entries.
From this table I need to create a second table that has the total sum of items per each quarter. Something like:

| QUARTER | total items |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 2022 | 6 |
| Q1 2023 | 6 |
| Q3 2022 | 2 |

This table should update the result each time a new row is added to the table "# items".
Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: `Power Query` or with New Excel Functions

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I tried pivot table but cannot select 2 columns... How can I do that? I always use pivot table on single column.... I'm not expert :(

Comment: Go through it : **[Pivot-Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**

Comment: Or, **[Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/group-by)**

Comment: [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra6bW.gif)

Comment: @JvdV this is what I was trying to do :O  If I do the same I receive the following error:

"Data source reference is not valid"

I just noticed that I've selected the entire column (since I do not know how many row will be added in the future) and in my excel file the "quarter" and "# items" columns are not consecutive (e.g.,  "quarter" column is A, "# items" column is D.

Comment: Make your original data a table (Ctrl+T).

Comment: The links I have provided, where in Microsoft Documentations. it clearly shows the steps. I dont know why you dont follow. @user3472065

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya thanks! I was watching the documentation but then JvdV gif gave me the hint. Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an excel formula for that as follows, in case you don't want to use a Pivot table for that:

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A7),SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)))
```

If you don't have `HSTACK` function available, you can use `CHOOSE` as follows:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2}, UNIQUE(A2:A7),SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)))
```

or using `LET` function to avoid repetitions:

```
=LET(A,A2:A7, B, B2:B7, ux, UNIQUE(A),HSTACK(ux, SUMIFS(B,A,ux)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a `SUMIF` function for this. It would look something like this:

```
SUMIF(Quarter,Q1 2022, # Items)
```

Comment: Can you review your syntax? That doesn't appear to be valid.